# C - fscanf not reading number correctly from text file

Tags: c, pointers, reference, scanf

I am new to C and I am trying to make my int a equal to 4. The 4 is being read from a text file however when I print a out it prints out 32767.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Component.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("text.txt","r");
    int a;

    fscanf(fp,"%d",&a);
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open");
    }

    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: You did not check that the file did open. `if(fp == NULL) {/* error report */}`

Comment: I added the check and the file did open

Comment: Also, you did not `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: fscanf() also returns a value.  Not checking the result of library/system calls seems to be popular passtime on SO:(

Comment: I also checked by printing the output of the text file to the console and it worked. I'm just obviously not assigning the 4 to a correctly

Comment: I have also included <stdio.h> but have not shown it in the code snippet

Comment: Is that your entire program? If not, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is why the guidelines ask for MCVE, so that we don't have a stupid dialog as to what the program did or did not include.

Comment: Umm.. does the text file contain a unicode BOM?

Comment: After question update ... this is looking like a C++ question, not a C question.

Comment: Yes, what is that 'using namespace std;'??

Comment: Could you add a hex dump from the file you're reading?

Comment: Not related to the maim problem, I don't think leaving files open is a good practice.

Comment: Martin James is correct, you should check the return from fscanf.  Also, one quick way to determine if the function is being called properly is to initialize a to something **other** than 4.  Say, 5.  If it's still 5 after the fscanf call, then you likely do have some namespace/C++ problem, not C.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks right, except that you should test if `fopen` worked before `fscanf`. By the way, the number you get is the maximum value for an `int`
There is probably a problem with your file:

- No read permission
- file does not exist
- does not contain the right value

Also, why do you use C++ if you only use C functions?